# How to prevent Chrome (iOS) from scrolling past the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, ios, google-chrome, scroll

### Conditions

I have a rather simple website layout consisting of a sticky header, main content and a sticky footer.

The sticky header and footer have fixed heights and the main content takes up whatever space is left.

If the main content requires more space than available it will cause the html node to overflow and display a scrollbar.

### Minimal Reproduction

This is an unstyled version of the StackBlitz example below.

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <header style="position: sticky; top: 0; height: 80px">Header</header>

      <main>
         <p>0</p>
         <p>1</p>
         <p>2</p>
         <p>3</p>
         <p>4</p>
         <p>5</p>
         <p>6</p>
         <p>7</p>
         <p>8</p>
         <p>9</p>
         <p>10</p>
         <p>11</p>
         <p>12</p>
         <p>13</p>
         <p>14</p>
         <p>15</p>
         <p>16</p>
         <p>17</p>
         <p>18</p>
         <p>19</p>
         <p>20</p>
      </main>

      <footer style="position: sticky; bottom: 0; height: 80px">Footer</footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

### Expectations

When I scroll down I expect the browser to hit the bottom of the page and stop scrolling. The footer should be the last element shown on the page, directly bordering the browser's own controls.

I also expect browsers to handle this without me having to apply additional CSS or JavaScript that forces the browser to behave in a certain way. Behavior such as overscrolling is expected and even required.

These expectations are met on MacOS (Chrome, Safari, Firefox) and on iOS (Safari, Firefox).

**Behavior in Safari (iOS)**

[image: Image showing the behavior in Safari (iOS)]

### Problem

It does not work in Chrome for iOS (version 111.0.5563.72 in my case). Once one scrolls to the bottom of the page the browser will scroll past the page and show an empty space.

This space will have the background color of the html node and is roughly the same height as the viewport.

I've already tried applying multiple different potential solutions based on CSS and JavaScript but to no avail.

**Behavior in Chrome (iOS)**

[image: Image showing the behavior in Chrome (iOS)]

### Demo

I've provided a StackBlitz repository that can be used to reproduce this behavior.

To test it for yourself open this link in Chrome for iOS: https://js-jetsg3.stackblitz.io

Follow this link to view the source code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jetsg3

While testing my production app and the demo, I have noticed that very rarely it actually does behave the way I would expect it to, only for it to go back to its normal behavior after one or two refreshes.

### Questions

What can be done to prevent Chrome from scrolling past the bottom of the page?

If nothing can be done about this particular behavior, what can be done to keep the footer at the very bottom of the page, when Chrome scrolls past the bottom of the screen?

Comment: a very weird, annoying behaviour. I have it on the iPad. It’s not just your app. Try any website. It’ll have the same behaviour. Then restart your iOS device. Does it work properly then?